# Redirecting non-SSL-Traffic to SSL-Traffic correctly

Tags: tomcat, redirect, ssl, web, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a problem with my Tomcat server.

When I access my site on http:// beluka.net I get a security warning, which I want to go away. I rather want to redirect the user to https:// www.beluka.net. I guess the problem is my security constraint in the web.xml file which makes http://beluka.net redirect to https://beluka.net

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ROOT</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I also have a working rewrite rule which redirects all non-www-traffic to www-traffic which works fine, but the problem is my rewrite rule is just followed after I accept the security warning.

How can I open a "hole" in the web.xml security constraint for http:// beluka.net ?

my rewrite rule (using tuckey) is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<!--

Configuration file for UrlRewriteFilter
http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

-->
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <name>Primary Domain Name Check</name>
        <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.beluka.net</condition>  
        <from>^(.*)</from>
        <to type="permanent-redirect">https://www.beluka.net$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: And the security warning says ... ?

Comment: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain, the certificate is just valid for www.beluka.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

One would be to create a new virtual host for beluka.net and deploy a trivial web application that redirects every request to www.beluka.net. That way requests to http://beluka.net will be redirected to http://www.beluka.net and then to https://www.beluka.net and you won't get the mis-matched host warning.

An alternative way would be to re-order your certificate with a SAN for beluka.net. That way your certificate will be valid for beluka.net and www.beluka.net

There are probably other ways to do this too.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I already fixed it by adding the additional security constraint right after mine: 
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ROOT</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>